# 0x80070520 when adding binding with programmatically generated X509Certificate2 on remote server

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509certificate2, iis-bindings

I'm trying to programmatically install a X509Certificate2 on remote Server.
The X509Certificate2 is generated by merging a Private Key in PEM format and a .crt file provided by a certification authority.
The private key is associated to the certificate using Org.BouncyCastle library.

```
public static byte [] GenerateSignedCert(byte[] certBytes, byte[] pkBYtes, string certName)
        {
            MemoryStream certMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(certBytes);
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StreamReader(certMemoryStream));
            var cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)pemReader.ReadObject();
            MemoryStream pkMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(pkBYtes);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(new StreamReader(pkMemoryStream)).ReadObject();
            Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
            X509CertificateEntry certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(cert);
            store.SetCertificateEntry(certName, certEntry);
            store.SetKeyEntry(certName, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(keyPair.Private), new[] { certEntry });
            MemoryStream pfxStream = new MemoryStream();
            store.Save(pfxStream, new char[] {}, new SecureRandom());
            return pfxStream.ToArray();
        }
```

When I export the X509Certificate2 object to pfx file and import it manually on the server i don't have any problem.
But when i try to do it programmatically...

```
            //Used by X509Store to open certificate store on remote machine
            string remoteIpAddress = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostIP"].ToString();
            //Username used by WrapperImpersonationContext to impersonate user
            string uName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostUser"].ToString();
            //Password used by WrapperImpersonationContext to impersonate user
            string pWord = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostPassword"].ToString();
            //Domain used by WrapperImpersonationContext to impersonate user
            string dMain = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostDomain"].ToString();
                DbManager dbManager = new DbManager();
                //Getting private key from database
                var certData = dbManager.GetCertificatiSitoWeb(idSitoWeb).Where(c => c.IDSitoWeb == idSitoWeb && c.IDCertificato == idCertificato).FirstOrDefault();
                //Getting website from database
                string website = dbManager.GetSitoWebByID(idSitoWeb).FirstOrDefault().NomeSito;
                
                //Impersonating a user that is granted to connect on remote machine
                WrapperImpersonationContext impersonationContext = new WrapperImpersonationContext(dMain, uName, pWord);
                impersonationContext.Enter();

                //Defining flags for X509Certificate2 instance
                X509KeyStorageFlags flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet;
                //Generating certificate with private key
                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(GenerateSignedCert(signedCertBytes, certData.PrivateKey, website), string.Empty, flags);
                byte[] certFileData = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, string.Empty);
                X509Certificate2 installableCert = new X509Certificate2(certFileData, string.Empty, flags);
                
                //Connecting to the store on remote machine
                using (X509Store store = new X509Store($@"\\{remoteIpAddress}\My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
                {
                    //Open the store
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
                    //Add certificate to the store
                    store.Add(installableCert);
                    //Close the store
                    store.Close();
                    //If a binding already exist for this website remove it
                    using (var svrMgr = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(remoteIpAddress))
                    {
                        Site site = svrMgr.Sites[website];
                        if (site != null)
                        {
                            Binding binding = site.Bindings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BindingInformation == $"*:443:{website}");
                            if (binding != null)
                            {
                                site.Bindings.Remove(binding);
                                svrMgr.CommitChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Adding the new binding and define its certHash using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
                    using (var svrMgr = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(remoteIpAddress))
                    {
                        Site site = svrMgr.Sites[website];
                        if (site != null)
                        {
                            
                            Binding binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
                            binding.SetAttributeValue("SslFlags", Convert.ToInt32(1));
                            binding.CertificateHash = installableCert.GetCertHash(); //THIS LINE GIVES 0x80070520 ERROR
                            binding.Protocol = "https";
                            binding.BindingInformation = $"*:443:{website}";
                            site.Bindings.Add(binding);
                            svrMgr.CommitChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Leave Impersonating of the granted user
                impersonationContext.Leave();
```

There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)

When I save certFileData to a pfx file and import it manually i works fine but when import it programmatically it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install certificate with private key into remote certificate store. You have to call your code locally on a server.

Comment: What if I add it without private key? It's possible to define private key later?

Comment: Why the concept of the exportable keys flags if the certificate can't be installed remotely?

Comment: `It's possible to define private key later?` -- well, it is possible, though not very easy. And still, must be done only locally.

Comment: `Why the concept of the exportable keys flags if the certificate can't be installed remotely?` -- for backup purposes. Remote key installation is not supported because key transfer and key security cannot be guaranteed.